# What is the standard textual representation of Qt's types?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, deserialization, qmetatype

Edit:

I should clarify: I am seeking to serialize the values, not just the name of the type.

---

Is there a human-readable/textual format for Qt's builtin types? (For example, the ones registered in QMetaType or QVariant::Type.)

Looking at the source of QSettings, that "ini" format is created manually. There are giant switch blocks that manually serialize and deserialize the "ini" representation. It is also, unfortunately, not a standard - because it is part of the "private" implementation of QSettings.

Or is there no standard whatsoever for textual representation of Qt types?

Comment: I think not. I would suggest QVariant/QVariantMap types, and JSON as something to research.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass {};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyClass)

QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue<MyClass>(MyClass());
std::cout << var.typeName() << std::endl;
```

will print "MyClass". You can do it with any registered type as well: `QMetaType::typeName(qMetaTypeId<int>())`

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific about what I am looking into.

Comment: @SaburoutaMishima, use `QDataStream` with `QFile` and serialize/deserialize values as `QVariant`s. `QVariant::typeName()` prints typename, `QVariant::toString()` will print textual representation of value of almost any type. Funny thing is that `QVariant` can even be `QVariantList` or `QVariantMap`, so serializing whole trees of data is possible with one class